# Rails w/ ActiveRecord Sessions and Restful-authentication: when does the sessions table get written to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, restful-authentication

Warning: some of this may be very wrong-headed, so please let me know if my assumptions are incorrect.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm using restful-authentication for login. However, as I am using flex/ruby_amf for my UI, I have to separately authenticate each connection from flex.

The way I decided to do that was by having the log-in screen redirect to the embedded flash page, inserting the session-id as a flashvar. The flash app sends the session-id with every request, and a before filter on all of the relevant controllers checks to see if the user associated with the session identified by the session-id is logged on.

The way I associate a user with session is by adding a 'user_id' column to the sessions table, and doing an sql "update sessions set user_id...'" type query called from the login function.

However, the user_id only gets updated the 2nd time the user logs in. A little investigating showed that the record in the sessions table does not yet exist during execution of the login function.

So, if everything up to this point makes sense, and conforms to best-practices, etc., then my question is:

At what point in time is the record in the sessions table created? Is there a way to update the session object in the login function and have rails write the user_id to the database for me?

The behavior of sessions in rails is a real mystery to me. I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: PS: I found a discussion about updating the sessions table here:
http://www.nabble.com/Rails-2.3-Sessions-td22720164.html

Comment: OK, I've been researching the problem a little more, and I think that one of the false assumptions I've been making is that the session object corresponds to a row in the session table. I was hoping that I could do session[:user_id] = Users.authenticate(name, pass) and then do a session.save to write it to the DB. In actuality (correct me if I'm wrong!), the session object appears in encoded form as the the data column.

Here is another link saying that what I'm doing is basically correct:
http://scottiestech.info/2009/04/02/rails-23-how-to-access-custom-columns-in-the-sessions-table/

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 2.3, the session is saved after the Rack application has finished its processing. In traditional Rails applications, this will be after the request is fully processed: before filters, controller action, view rendering, and after filters. Look in `actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/vendor/rack-1.1.pre/rack/session/abstract/id.rb`.

If you think about it, this makes perfect sense. Writing the session to its store every time you place something in the session would incur a lot of extra overhead.

It's Rails, so if you want to mess with it enough, sure, you can monkeypatch yourself a way to write the session to store anytime you wish. I don't recommend it. You'll end up having to rework the code constantly as Rails evolves.

You are right that for ActiveRecord::SessionStore, one row does map to one session. The `data` column is an encoded form of every object you put in the session. Each time a request comes in, Rails has to reconstitute the session as it existed by creating new instances of all the objects you previously stored in it.